# Enter key JTextField

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have a JTextField with an Actionlistener to it. Now I want it to do certain things when I press enter. I am using a shared ActionListener so trying to do a getSource on the JTextField but it doesn't work! Hope anyone can help.

```
JTextField txtProductAantal = new JTextField(String.valueOf(WinkelApplication.getBasket().getProductAmount(productdelete)));
            txtProductAantal.setBounds(340, verticalPosition + i * productOffset, 40, 20);
            txtProductAantal.addActionListener(this);
            add(txtProductAantal); 

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource() == btnEmptyBasket) {
            WinkelApplication.getBasket().empty();
            WinkelApplication.getInstance().showPanel(new view.CategoryList());
        }

        if(event.getSource() == txtProductAantal){
            String productgetal = txtProductAantal.getText();
            txtProductAantal.setText(productgetal);
            WinkelApplication.getInstance().showPanel(new view.Payment());
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) `txtProductAantal.setBounds(..)`  Use layouts to avoid the next 17 problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- have to create an temporary `Object` for comparisons

for example

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == btnEmptyBasket) {
           //...........
        } else if (source == txtProductAantal) {
           //........... 
        } else {

        }
    }
```

- or there are only `JTextFields` (avoiding `instanceof` inside `if - else` statement) you can casting Object to `JTextField` directly

`JTextField source = (JTextField) event.getSource();`

EDIT,

- `one from the next adviced 17 problems.`
- `please to read suggestion by @Andrew Thompson, again`

  - `1) For better help sooner, post an SSCCE.`
  - `2) txtProductAantal.setBounds(..)`
  - `Use layouts to avoid the next 17 problems.`

my code works as I'm expected

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTextFieldAndActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frm = new JFrame("JTextFieldAndActionListener");
    private JTextField one = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField two = new JTextField();
    private JTextField three = new JTextField();

    public JTextFieldAndActionListener() {
        one.addActionListener(this);
        two.addActionListener(this);
        three.addActionListener(this);
        frm.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frm.add(one);
        frm.add(two);
        frm.add(three);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocation(400, 300);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == one) {
            System.out.println("firing from JTextField one");
        } else if (source == two) {
            System.out.println("firing from JTextField two");
        } else if (source == three) {
            System.out.println("firing from JTextField three");
        } else {
            System.out.println("something went wrong");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTextFieldAndActionListener ie = new JTextFieldAndActionListener();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

print_out me on ENTER key

```
run:
firing from JTextField one
firing from JTextField two
firing from JTextField three
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)
```

Comment: Still does not work. I have put a system out on the textfield's if, but it just doesn't react on the enter button.

Comment: @DaViDa : It does work too good. You can test the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) yourself by looking at this [**link**](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/Example.java).

Comment: I think something else is wrong that's why it doesn't work but thanks all for showing me a good way of doing this!